How to run a one-time pipeline using gitlab REST API?
I'm researching how to run a pipeline without adding a .gitlab-ci.yml file.
I want to know if it's possible to use the REST API to run a pipeline (or a job) and manually pass the .gitlab-ci.yml content when executing it.
My current solution is as follows, to write the .gitlab-ci.yml file like this:
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  image: 192.168.1.111/library/docker:dind-1.0.2
  only:
    variables:
      - $IS_RUN == "true"
  script:
    - |
      curl --location --request GET "http://192.168.1.111:8888/getMyCustomShell" | sh

Then, I manually pass the IS_RUN parameter when running the pipeline. However, this approach has a flaw: no matter how many scripts I have, only one stage is displayed in the pipeline.
This confuses me because my stages are dynamic and cannot be explicitly declared in .gitlab-ci.yml.

You have to make sure you write a gitlab yml config that uses variables, which you can pass while triggering via API.

@BijayRegmi Yes, I'm sure I'm using variables, and it's currently working fine. But I want to know how to define a dynamic .gitlab-ci.yml file or not define it at all, but instead pass it temporarily.
